# Create an interactive map using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to implement a little map "like" Google Maps. Its a fictive one (Game Map). I should have the ability to zoom and move around. Also i would like to be able to put some markes on it and do a very basic routing.

My question is now purly conceptual. How would you realize this?
Map as background that scales and moves. Then an overlay like a Canvas object to draw over it? Somene has experience with this? I don't really know if this is the right approach.

Thank You.

Comment: There are some tools out there (OpenStreetMap, GeoServer) that would allow you to build a map server that hosts the tiles of your map data with a pretty decent maps api on the front end - not sure if that would meet your needs or not.

Comment: What kind of form is your original map data in?

Comment: Consider asking this on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: Form is a picture right now. I could of course make a mapping on my own with some pathpoints or similar. BTW Ty for the link Antony looks like an awsome page i didn't know yet :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully get what you want but with [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) ou can create you own **vector(!)** maps with [markers](http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/) and [custom colors](http://jvectormap.com/examples/random-colors/).

So I think it will help you.

Comment: This hint was awsome. Ty very much.

Comment: A question after seeing this, does this allow me to create a custom map? not realworld info(like a map from lord of the rings) or is it limited to the earth map?

Comment: @Kostas They have exmple of Map of the Mall (http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/), you can use same for your custom map.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever used a program called Impact?

its really useful when building games in HTML5

http://impactjs.com/

Comment: Ty for the link. Actually I am not programming a game. I am mapping an existing one. So I don't think a Tile-Map can help me here.